# Flutter - How to force flutter_localizations to the desired lang?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-localizations

I have integrated flutter localizations dependent of system language, works very well.
But I want to "force" language programmatically, without matters on system language.

My app root:

```
return GetMaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('sr', ''),
        Locale('en', ''),
      ],
```

My lang config file:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_sr.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

Any every next new entering into the app will "keep" the user choose preferred language.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the locale attribute to your MaterialApp, like that:

```
// Content from your MaterialApp

locale: const Locale('sr'),

// More content from your MaterialApp
```

If you need change in another part of your app, you can change de Locale in your AppLocalizations class.

Comment: Cool, tank you. 
But, can I change ``locale`` programmatically? If the user press any button, to change it?